# Apache 2 restart fails

Tags: apache-2.2

Merry Christmas!

I´m setting up a Ubuntu 12.04 webserver. therefore I installed Apache2, also mod_security.
I edited the configuration regarding mod_security. Everything worked fine yesterday.

Today I´m tyring to restart Apache, but this fails with following error:

```
$ /etc/init.d/apache2 restart

Syntax error on line 2 of /etc/apache2/conf.d/DEADJOE:
Invalid command '***', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
Action 'configtest' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
   ...fail!
```

I checked apache error Log but couldn´t find anything same in syslog. 
The content of /etc/apache2/conf.d/DEADJOE is:

```
*** These modified files were found in JOE when it aborted on Mon Dec 23 14:48:44 2013
*** JOE was aborted because the terminal closed

*** File '(Unnamed)'
/etc/modsecurity/modsecurity.conf
/etc/apache2/mods-available/mod-security.conf
/etc/modsecurity/modsecurity.conf
/var/log/apache2/error.log
/etc/apache2/conf.d/modsecurity.conf
/etc/apache2
security
/etc/modsecurity/modsecurity.conf
/var/log/apache2/error.log
/etc/modsecurity/modsecurity.conf
/var/log/apache2/error.log
```

Thanks for any help!

Toni

Comment: Rams! Got it, the Problem was the File DEADJOE itself! I deleted it and Apache is running again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the joe editor crashed, and produced some kind of dump. Move /etc/apache2/conf.d/DEADJOE to somewhere else (e.g. /var/tmp) and then try restarting.
Alternatively you can configure apache to only look for configuration files with a certain extension

```
Include /etc/apache2/sites-available/*.conf
```